# How can I make a vertically scrolling appwidget for LauncherPro, ADW, etc?

Tags: android

A small number of appwidgets on the market are able to scroll vertically in some of the custom launcher replacements. How can I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the mailing list here http://groups.google.com/group/android-appwidget-extensions
There are hints and tutorials.
Anyways, with the (hopefully) coming soon honeycomb release that allows more kinds of remoteviews, this extensions may vary or be completely discarded.

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly the resource I was scouring the web for.